# Accessing and returning nested array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, nested

I can't seem to figure this out. I just get an undefined return.

```
let test = [1, 2, 3, 4, [6, 7, 8]];
```

How do I return the index `[2]` of `test[4]`?

I'm not even sure I'm asking the question properly.
Basically, I want to interact with 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maybe help you understand what is going on.
If you write

```js
let test = [1, 2, 3, 4, [6, 7, 8]];
```

you create an array (which is more like a list if you compare it to other languages). Every entry has its own datatype. So in the example we have the first 4 elements which are just numbers and the fifth entry which is another `Array`.

With the `[]` operator we address certain elements inside the array. If we want the first entry we can use `test[0]` and should get back `1`.

You now want to access an element in the array inside an array. So you first address the array in the array. `test[4]` this will give you back `[6, 7, 8]` and now you can do the same thing again and address this new array. You could write it this way

```js
let test = [1, 2, 3, 4, [6, 7, 8]];
let innerArray = test[4];
let element = innerArray[2];
```

The example above is just to better understand what is going on. In practice you will just do `test[4][2]` and it will basically to the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
let test = [1, 2, 3, 4, [6, 7, 8]];
console.log(test[4][2])
```